# How to change Comment font in Pandoc

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

[image: Codeblock with pandoc]

Hi I am trying to convert my markdown files to PDF via pandoc. i used the command `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf` and the result is shown above. I noticed the font for the comments is different than the font for the regular code. Is there any way to change the font of the comments? Been trying to figure out for the life of me but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: you can try to redefine the `CommentTok` environment... analogous to e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154528/how-to-change-the-background-color-and-border-of-a-pandoc-generated-blockquote